# jQuery Mobile ScrollView "initialization"

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I'm using the scrollview experimental feature of jQuery Mobile:

```
<div class="carousel" data-scroll="xp">
  ... my position:absolute very large div ...
</div>
```

as described here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/

Now I need to change the ".carousel" content dynamically:

I make an ajax call in order to retrieve my new scrollview content.

The content loads and shows in my div correctly, but it's not scrollable anymore!

How can I rebind my "carousel" to its scrolling original behavior?

*Does a ".scrollview()" function actually exist?*

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included this plugin? http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js

Please look at this script to see an example how to call it
http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview.js

Here they call `.scrollview()` and `.scrolllistview()`